# Sentence construction question

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I want to express the following:

1. John's work has been important because of its great impact on society.
2. John's work has been important because of its relevance to society.

For this, I constructed the next sentence:

"John's work has been important because of its great impact and relevance to society."

I am not sure if this is correct because "to" doesn't seem to match sentence (1) and (2) at the same time.

Comment: If you feel you must put both in one sentence, you need to say 'because of its impact on, and relevance to society'.

Comment: Your question deserves a direct answer, but I'd suggest that this combination is redundant anyway. Something that has great impact is naturally "relevant." It's just extra words for no reason.

Comment: This is a question which frequently troubles native speakers. Kate's comment certainly gives the preferred answer in writing. In speech, I think many people would say what you concluded.